# connot pass parameter by reference

Tags: php, mysqli

I keep getting cannot pass parameter 2 by refference, though name in form, variable type is ok.
Ive seen the other's cases and they seemed reasonable, but i cant find my error here.

```html
 $sid = $_POST['staff_id'];
 $sname = $_POST['staff_name'];
 $sgender = $_POST['gender'];
 $sdob = $_POST['staff_dob'];
 $sbranch = $_POST['branch'];
 $stell = $_POST['tel_no'];
 $position = $_POST['position'];
 $salary =$_POST['salary'];
 $login = $_POST['staff_login'];
 $password = $_POST['staff_password'];
}
else{     
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO
              staff (staff_id, staff_name, gender, staff_dob, branch, tell_no, position, salary, staff_login, staff_password) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param('ssssssiiss', '$sid', '$sname', '$sgender', '$sdob', '$sbranch', '$stell', '$position', '$salary', '$login', '$password');
```

here's my html form:

```
      <form method="post" action="">

      <input type="text" name="staff_id" placeholder="your given ID">
      <input type="text" name="staff_name" placeholder="Full Name"/>
      <label class="formlabel">Your gender:</label>
      <input type="text" name="gender" placeholder="male/female">
      <label class="formlabel"><b>Date of Birth:</b></label>
      <input type="date" name="staff_dob">
      <input type="text" name="branch" placeholder="Your branch ID">
      <input type="tel" name="tel_no" placeholder="your telephone number">
      <label class="formlabel"><b>Your position</b></label>
      <select name="position">
        <option value="1"> Asisstant</option>
        <option value="2"> Supervisor</option>
        <option value="3"> Manager</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" name="salary" placeholder="your salary ammount">
      <input type="text" name="staff_login" placeholder="Make your new login">
     <input type="password" name="staff_password" placeholder="Enter your new password">
      <button type="submit" name="btn-register" value="submit">Register</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: and also `'$sid'` this is wrong, instead use `$sid` without quotes

Comment: What's with the else prior to the sqli? You need those post variables it looks like...

Comment: Sure thanks, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ' ' around all your variables. What it's saying is you can't pass in a reference variable it needs to be the value with a bind_param

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssiiss', $sid, $sname, $sgender, $sdob, $sbranch, $stell, $position, $salary, $login, $password);
```

Why are you bringing in the $_POST variables but also having an else before mysqli?

Comment: I was trying to solve the issues before and it made me do some relocations, gotta fix this mistake now.

Comment: No problemo :) !

Answer (score -1):

You have to understand the difference between a **string** and a **variable**.

Variables are not strings. And should be written **without quotes.**